# Theos with iOS SDK 5 and method porting

Tags: iphone, ios, methods, sdk, makefile

So I am attempting to bring the iOS 5 SDK to the Theos Makefile system. I have the following things working: Private Frameworks, Multitasking from UIKit. Since Theos uses SDK 3. This jump to SDK 5 breaks a few methods as they're deprecated. Keep in mind that I'll be using RPetrich's headers on GitHub for this. With that in mind, I'm trying to add the following dismissal code to the UIViewController header.

```
- (void)dismissViewControllerAnimated: (BOOL)flag completion: (void (^)(void))completion __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_5_0);
```

This makes my compiler complain about the (void (^) (void)) part. I've tried replacing it with BOOL and just a regular void and then just calling nil when using the method. Doesn't work that way. I wanted to know if there was a way I can successfully compile with this method, or if I can somehow use dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: again. Some reason I can still use presentModalViewController:animated: and it says they both WILL be deprecated. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

change default compiler gcc/g++ to apple's clang/clang++

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: some modern objective-c syntax that apple added recently don't support gcc/g++(or i don't know how to make gcc support like block...) , so the simplest way to solve it is using clang(llvm)